# Adding Current Product page Variant ID/SKU to webform submission Drupal 8

Tags: commerce, webforms

I have product type event, this event have registration fees if price value not zero.

Product page built with views and I embed related webform inside it.

am using module called commerce webform order: which add handler to webform to create order and redirect user after submit webform to checkout page.

Currently I use fixed selected variant as screenshot below

[image]

This field needs to be filed with product ID, and accept token. However I don't have direct token can be used in webform as hidden field to read this value (I want to store this value like screenshot below)
[image]

Any ideas how can this be done? or at least what token can be read in webform to set this value (I did some research and did try [webform_submission:source-entity:variation_sku]) but its not working.